# R: how to minimize a function with data using DEoptim

Tags: r, function, optimization, curve-fitting

I would like to use DEoptim to minimize the square error of the given function to fit a 4 parameter power law to some data:

```
expfun <- function(p,data){
    res = eval(expression(((data[,2]-((p[1]+p[2]*data[,1])*(1-exp(-(data[,1]-p[3])/p[4]))))^2)))
    return(sum(res))
}

low = c(-100,-50,-50,0)
high = c(100,50,50,20)

fit = DEoptim(expfun, low, high, DEoptim.control(itermax=500, trace=False))
```

But I'm not sure how to make the data available to `DEoptim` when `expfun` is passed. What is the correct way to do this?

**EDIT:** Here is some (mock) data I can provide... I am not so familiar with R but am interfacing with it through python at the moment. A small clip of my input matrix, `data`, looks like this (from a pandas dataframe):

```
    x       y
0   33.8    19.734328
1   34.2    19.855713
2   34.4    20.005075
3   36.0    20.023766
4   36.1    20.921509
5   36.3    21.505115
6   36.6    24.600343
7   36.8    25.424239
8   37.4    26.335077
9   38.2    26.421332
10  41.6    26.729980
11  42.4    35.006403
12  46.0    37.647034
13  47.3    38.058187
14  47.8    38.177062
15  58.5    41.061019
16  79.1    43.005465
```

My data is loaded in through two numpy arrays `x` and `y` (again python) into a FloatVector:

```
m = np.concatenate((x,y))
data = matrix(R.FloatVector(m), len(x))
```

which gives this information if I output it in a console:

```
<Matrix - Python:0x000000001316B948 / R:0x0000000011FCC4C0>
[19.734328, 19.855713, 20.005075, ..., 38.177062, 41.061019, 43.005465]
```

I don't know how useful this extra information will be but I hope it helps

Comment: Where is the `data` object? R doesn't know `False`.

Comment: The data object would be a matrix in this case which has two columns.

Comment: I should have phrased my comment differently - give us the (mock) data. :)

Comment: Sorry about that. Easier said than done for me - right now I am interfacing with R through Python so knowledge is a little limited in R right now but in my edit I show what the data looks like from my dataframe and how it gets put into an R matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `?DEoptim`, there is an argument called `...`, for which it says that the arguments passed to `...` will be passed on to `fn`. Consequently, I would do it like so:

```
my.data <- read.table(text = "x       y
33.8    19.734328
34.2    19.855713
34.4    20.005075
36.0    20.023766
36.1    20.921509
36.3    21.505115
36.6    24.600343
36.8    25.424239
37.4    26.335077
38.2    26.421332
41.6    26.729980
42.4    35.006403
46.0    37.647034
47.3    38.058187
47.8    38.177062
58.5    41.061019
79.1    43.005465", header = TRUE)

expfun <- function(p, data){
  res = (data[,2]-((p[1]+p[2]*data[,1])*(1-exp(-(data[,1]-p[3])/p[4]))))^2
  sum(res)
}

low = c(-100,-50,-50,0)
high = c(100,50,50,20)

require(DEoptim)
fit = DEoptim(expfun, low, high, DEoptim.control(itermax=500, trace = FALSE), data = my.data)
summary(fit)

***** summary of DEoptim object ***** 
best member   :  72.03075 -0.33433 27.12013 18.7239 
best value    :  55.70625 
after         :  500 generations 
fn evaluated  :  1002 times 
*************************************
```

Comment: Awesome! Easier than I thought